# GIT repo downloads but doesn't checkout

Tags: download, repository, checkout

I am a video game artist, so I have no idea how to code, nor do I speak the language, so please be gentle.

We have a Unity Project on Git with 4 active users including myself. 
2 of the 4 of us have downloaded the project and it is working as it should. (The 3rd person hadn't tried yet).

I am the one who pushed the project from my windows 7, i7, machine, which the other 2 individuals are using. For some reason, when I pushed up, it did not 'check out.' If I understand correctly, the term 'checkout' means that the cloud is connected to my local repo.

I have tried 4 times to pull the project down... every time, it will download the project locally to my machine, but it fails to check out.

```
Checking out files: 100% (27463/27463), done.
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

I am currently using GITHUB DESKTOP to pull the project. I am currently attempting to download from SourceTree this time.

I have over 500GB of space on my local drive, so that can't be it. The other two guys have been helping me find solutions, however, it's time to ask for help, its been 4 days of actual time spent looking for a solution.

Comment: Try cloning the repo again in a separate location?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/208 solves your problem?

Answer (score 1):

My man Xavi found the answer! Unity names some files extravagantly long:

```
error: unable to create file myProject/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi@1.0.2/Tests/Runtime/NetworkBehaviourCallbacksOrderOnTheHost/Resources/PlayerCallbacksOrderOnTheHost_PlayerPrefab.prefab.meta: Filename too long!
```

Friggin Unity.

Xavi said to do this:
1. Go to your main drive

2. Click on the Users folder
3. Go to whichever folder is under your account that you log onto your computer with (it's usually just your name)
4. There should be a file called .gitconfig, it's able to be opened up in notepad
5. Type this in at the bottom of the doc:

   [core]
       longpaths = true